# Java fixing a "exception in thread 'main' java.util.NoSuchelementException"

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. Working on classwork. I can get the right answer to the following problem, yet its still marked wrong by the textbook and says I have "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException". I've tried all sorts of things to fix the error, but I only make things worst.

**Question:**

Read string integer value pairs from input until "End" is read. For each string read:

If the following integer read is less than 25, output the string followed by ": low on stock".
Otherwise, output the string followed by ": well stocked".
End each output with a newline.

Ex: If the input is Bookcase 30 Hammock 2 Bed 5 End, then the output is:

Bookcase: well stocked
Hammock: low on stock
Bed: low on stock

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Inputkey {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

      String input;
      input = scnr.next();
      int num;
      num = scnr.nextInt();
      String find = "End";
      boolean val = input.contains(find);
  
      while (!val){
         if (num < 25) {
            System.out.println (input + ": low on stock");
            input = scnr.next();
            num = scnr.nextInt();
         }
         else {
            System.out.println(input + ": well stocked");
            input = scnr.next();
            num = scnr.nextInt();            
         }
     
      }
      

   }
}
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of the exception to your question.

Comment: But stepping through your program wityh the debugger will help. And think about `val`. When can it become true?

Comment: The full exception is: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
 at Inputkey.main(Inputkey.java:18)

Comment: Note for future: Please put stack traces in the question itself, as text, formatted in a code block; if you've already posted the question, then you can update it via an [edit].

Comment: There is no [tag:multithreading] here. Don't tag indiscriminately. But there is a [tag:java.util.scanner].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never update `val` in your loop. Worse, once you read `End` you still try and read an `int` regardless. I would eliminate `val` and use an infinite loop. Break when you read `End`. Something like,

```
while (true) {
    String input = scnr.next();
    if ("End".equals(input)) {
         break;
    }
    int num = scnr.nextInt();            
    if (num < 25) {
        System.out.println(input + ": low on stock");
    } else {
        System.out.println(input + ": well stocked");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the responses and explaining what I was doing wrong. That worked.  Hurray!

Answer (score -1):

base on your code, you should make some changes, like:

> ```
> import java.util.Scanner;
>
> public class Inputkey {
>    public static void main(String[] args) {
>       Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
>
>       String input = scnr.next();
>       int num = scnr.nextInt();
>       String find = "End";
>       boolean val = input.contains(find);
>   
>       while (!val){
>          if (num < 25) {
>             System.out.println (input + ": low on stock");
>          }
>          else {
>             System.out.println(input + ": well stocked");
>          }
>          input = scnr.next();
>          val = input.contains(find);
>          if(val){
>              break;
>          }
>          num = scnr.nextInt();
>       }
>    }
> }
> ```

but this structure is not so good.
I suggest you can change to Elliott Frisch ones.

Comment: Mere code is not an answer. You have to explain.

Comment: Base on Romy code, I modified them to make them work correctly, is that a correct answer? What's an "answer" meaning?
Unlike school work, there is often more than one solution in real life.